# How to reset a JSpinner to min value

Tags: java, jspinner

I need to reset a JSpinner to its min value. I've tried get it from model:

```
spinner.setValue(((SpinnerNumberModel) spinner.getModel()).getMinimum());
```

But i've got IllegalArgumentException...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if your model doesn't have a minimum, or if its minimum is a `Comparable` that is not a `Number`.

Comment: My bad. You are right. Doesn't have a minimum value. Thanks.